# Ethernet connectivity doesn't happen automatically; only after restarting the router

Tags: networking, macbook, imac, wired-networking

When I'm at home I use two general-use computers: a desktop (iMac manufactured Late 2013 running macOS Sierra v. 10.12.6) and a laptop (MacBook Pro manufactured mid-2012 running the same OS as the desktop). I don't use WiFi at home; both computers connect to the internet with a wire. I use the same wire with both computers, detaching and re-attaching one end of it.

Until a few days this worked smoothly, but then the wire's little plastic clasp broke, and I replaced it with a new wire (PATCH CORD CAT .5E FTP STRANDED 26AWG 4 PAIRS TIA /EIA 568A). Now when I attach the wire to one of the computers after it has been attached to the other computer, the newly attached computer doesn't connect to the Internet, even after 5 minutes' wait.

Only after restarting the router (i.e. unplugging it from the outlet, waiting 30 seconds, replugging it, and waiting some 3 minutes) does the Internet connection re-establish. (If I detach the wire from the computer and then reattach it to the same computer without connecting it to the other computer in-between, the Internet connection is established automatically.)

How can I get my computers to behave as in the past, when all I needed to do in order to connect a computer to the Internet was to attach the wire to it?

---

**A partially successful attempt to solve the problem**

1. On computer A, while connected to the Internet, I opened Settings > Network.
2. I took a screenshot.
3. I changed the "Configure IPv4" item from *Using DHCP* to *Manually*.
4. I filled-in the settings as they were captured in the screen cap.
5. I clicked "Apply". **The Internet connection remained intact.**
6. I detached the wire from computer A, and attached it to computer B.
7. I repeated steps 1-5 on computer B, except instead of taking a new screen cap, I used the one from step 2, so that the settings on both computers were the same. **Computer B was unable to connect to the Internet with these settings.**
8. I detached the wire from computer B, and attached it to computer A. **After a few seconds, computer A connected to the Internet automatically.**

Comment: I think it's pretty likely that the wire you have is miswired. Did you wire it yourself or did you buy it preassembled? Are you 100% sure the pins-to-pairs mapping is correct?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I bought it preassembled. There are no pins involved; the connection point looks like one of [these](http://cjdellatore.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/14091d1357164106-internet-connection-drops-every-couple-minutes-cable-sxchu-internet1.jpg).

Comment: It is still possible that by bad luck you happened to get a bad cable. What did the packaging on the cable say? Did it have a category rating?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: As far as I recall, the cable was not packaged, or maybe it was inside a nylon bag. What I'll do is, I'll buy a new cable at a different store. Hopefully this will solve the problem. I will report back once I've changed the cable.

Comment: Does the cable have any labeling on it? If not, why do you think it's suitable for your application?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: No labels on the cable, but there's text printed on it: PATCH CORD CAT .5E FTP STRANDED 26AWG 4 PAIRS TIA /EIA 568A. I have no compelling reason to think it's suitable for my application (namely, connecting to the Internet), except the fact that it does in fact enable me to connect to the Internet, as evidenced by the fact that I am posting these very lines over this cable.

Comment: Cat 5E patch cord should work. EIA/568A is a proper wiring standard for Ethernet and does ensure the right pins-to-pairs mapping. The cable should work if it's not damaged. If the cable is not correct, or is damaged, it can fail in strange ways including working with some devices and not others.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The cable does work, if by "work" you mean "enables connecting my computers to the Internet". It only fails to work when it is detached from one computer and reattached to the other one. In this situation the Internet connection is not established automatically; instead, I have to restart the router and step through the "Diagnostics..." wizard twice, and only then is the Internet connection established.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is exactly as you say, it indeed points to the new cable. One more scenario I could see: for ethernet, there are 'straight' cables and such where Rx and Tx are crossed. Up til the early 2000s, the difference did matter, after that, ethernet ports were usually able to guess the right configuration. So maybe the cable is good per se, but between router and macs, guessing went better with the other type.

If that wasn't it, next thing to check would be if dhcp is set to work on both router and macs, unless you know what fixed/static ip is and want to use that. Future helpers will probably benefit, too, if you detail what answers you give to what questions in your step 3.

Comment: So what practical advice could you give me to help solve the problem?

Comment: I've changed answer already. But if after sucessfully connecting, you go to settings-network and have the properties of the eth connection displayed, what does it say? What is your ip, and is there a field saying automatic/dhcp OR manual?

Comment: And, although I might have logged out by the time you read this: what happens if you do not reboot the router?

Comment: I've added more details to my post. If I do not reboot the router, nothing happens, i.e. the Internet connection does not reestablish automatically, even after 5 minutes' wait.

Comment: But does 2x wizard work without reboot? But first try to give the config of the eth connection when it finally works. You can also log into your router and make sure dhcp is on. It usually is on by default, but who knows. Rebooting and re-running wizards may have lost some setting.

Comment: I've just seen your changes. One thing in play could be that your router takes more time than you think to a) boot up and b) really conect to interned (wan) . That still doesn't explain loosing connection when switching computer.

Comment: I've changed my post again after conducting some experiments. I am now of the opinion that the "Diagnostics..." wizard has absolutely no bearing on the situation. It is only the restarting of the router that makes the difference.

Comment: A bit of repeated plugging out and in to remove possible minimal corrosion, and you could try to use your assigned ip address when all works, as a static ip, but you'll probably have to read up on that.

Comment: Horrible place for live counsel, you often overlap :) give the router time, as said, but do you know how to log into your router's configuration interface?

Comment: No, I don't know how to log into my router's configuration interface, but I can probably figure it out with Google and/or contacting my ISP's support line. However, ideally I'd like to avoid hard-wiring my router, since it was working fine until I bought a new wire.

Comment: I'm more or less at the end of my rope. Plugging out and in the mains, btw, is not the nicest way to reboot a router, especially if you do not wait long enough before plugging back in. Usually there's a button. Although that doesn't solve anything, I'd be curious if all still works if you plug out and in ethernet, but do not change computer. Also, for a more 'live' type of support, you could try freenode.net -> web chat -> channel ##networking .

Comment: I conducted another experiment inspired by your suggestion to change the router's configuration interface. I opened Settings > Network, and took a screenshot. I then changed the "Configure IPv4" item from "Using DHCP" to "Manually", typed-in the settings as they appeared in the screen cap, and clicked "Apply". The Internet connection remained intact. I then repeated the same procedure on computer B, except instead of taking a new screen cap, I used the one I took on computer A, so that the settings on both computers were the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, computer B was unable to connect to the Internet with these settings. However, when I reattached the wire to computer A, it now connected to the Internet automatically.

Comment: You didn't change anything on the router's side, you configured your macs. But well done otherwise. You might check of the network settings offer any 'advanced' settings, and if possible, give computer B the same mac address as computer A. But it looks like your router is using some overly clever settings after all the resbooting, i.e. only allowing 1 connection and identifying the 1st come computer. You usually get into your router by putting the 'gateway' ip into your browser, user and password are often guessable (1234,admin..), googleable by brand/model, or mentioned on box or by isp.

Comment: A last, last resort could be checking your router for a small hole to stick a pin into for a factory reset. There is a small risk the router will forget it's dsl connect parameters then, and hence that move should be discussed with your isp. They might also know the models pwd, or be able to perform remote maintainance, let them know you want the router to accept various connections/give various dhcp leases (in general, and particularly from a single eth port).

Comment: I tried to find my 'gateway' IP address by going to Settings > Network > Advanced... > TCP/IP > Router. However, when I copied the IP address listed there to the browser, a message was displayed that the browser was unable to connect to that address.